# Why does my CC give me cash back, when they get nothing from me?

Tags: credit-card

When I applied for my new credit card, I answered several questions.  In one of these I indicated that I pay off the balance of my card every month.  The bank is not getting interest from me, since I do this.  But I still get cash back for purchases I make with this card.

What is the bank getting out of the deal?

Comment: The tagged duplicate is a good answer, but in addition to merchant fees there's also a percentage of people who intend to always pay it off who eventually won't, and will end up paying interest, so the banks have that going for them too.

Answer (score 3):

Banks also charge the merchant each time you purchase something. This is why you will often see stores have a minimum purchase amount for credit cards, or ban some of the higher fee ones completely (Amex etc).